# Review "This post is locked"

Tags: support, review, review-audits

I had a problem when trying to edit a new users post in reviewing. Any time I attempted it said "this post is locked". Anyone know why?

Comment: which post is this? Sounds like rejected migration

Comment: It was an answer. The post was made by this user http://superuser.com/users/206280/kokin?tab=answers but it doesn't show up under his answers.

Comment: The post was locked (prevents any changes and comments) and deleted days ago. Should probably not be in any queue. Could be a weird review audit given how wrong all the information on the review page is.

Answer (score 2):

The post you [refer to](https://superuser.com/questions/534776/batch-remove-pdf-password-using-acrobat-pro-11-or-other-software/564462#564462) was flagged and removed as spam 6 days ago, and I believe it was shown as part of [review audit](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/review-audits/info).